# Validation based in async Validators

Tags: angularjs

Hello im using async Validators to check if a email exist in my database, and it checks well, it gives me the correct http request, it works fine using for example in a first time registration, it will check to see if the user exist in my database. The problem is for example when i use to recover the password. The documentation says:

"if $http is used then it is important that the server returns a success HTTP response code
 * in order to fulfill the validation and a status level of `4xx` in order to reject the validation"

So what is happening to me is when the user insert the email in the recover password page, it gives a response of '400 - Bad request' and makes the form/input invalid. I need to change this beavihour, for when the 400 request is given to make the validation true and if the response is 200 make the validation false.

Example code Js:

```
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attribute, controller) {
        controller.$asyncValidators.uniqueEmail = function (email) {
            return $http
                .post('/api/email/availability', {value: email})
                then(function(response) {
                        //username exists, this means validation fails
                        return $q.reject('exists');
                      }, function(response) {
                        //username does not exist, therefore this validation passes
                        return true;
                })
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: create a plnkr to help others understand your issue better

Answer (score 0):

check the response object you get in the $http callback, it contains the status code.

[$http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

```
function(response) {
    if (response.status == 200) { return true; }
}
```

Comment: also note that the first function in the callback is for success, the second is for error handling. see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q